# Web crawler to extract data particular subset of html tags

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

1.

```
<p class="followText">Follow us</p>
<p><a class="symbol ss-social-circle ss-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/HowStuffWorks" target="_blank">Facebook</a></p>
```

2.

```
<p>Gyroscopes can be very perplexing objects because they move in peculiar ways and even seem to defy gravity. These special properties make ­gyroscopes extremely important in everything from your <a href="bicycle.htm">bicycle</a> to the advanced navigation system on the <a href="http://science.howstuffworks.com/space-shuttle.htm">space shuttle</a>. A typical <a href="airplane.htm">airplane</a> uses about a dozen gyroscopes in everything from its <a href="compass.htm">compass</a> to its autopilot. The Russian Mir space station used 11 gyroscopes to keep its orientation to <a href="http://science.howstuffworks.com/sun.htm">the sun</a>, and the <a href="http://science.howstuffworks.com/hubble.htm">Hubble Space Telescope</a> has a batch of navigational gyros as well. Gyroscopic effects are also central to things like <a href="http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/yo-yo.htm">yo-yos</a> and Frisbees!</p>
```

This is part of source of the website http://science.howstuffworks.com/gyroscope.htm, from which I'm trying to extract contents of the `<p>` tag from.

This is the code I'm using to do that

```
def trade_spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
  url = 'http://science.howstuffworks.com/gyroscope' + str(page) + ".htm"
  source_code = requests.get(url)
  plain_text = source_code.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
  for link in soup.findAll('p'):
      paragraph = link.string
      print paragraph
```

But I'm getting both types of data( both 1 and 2) inside the `p` tag.

I need to get only the data from the part 2 section and not part 1.

Please suggest me a way to leave out tags with attributes but keep the basic tags of the same `html` tag.